# In laravel 5 using DB::raw , how to retrieve mysql_info()?

Tags: mysql, pdo, laravel-5

How to get mysql_info (Affected Rows, Deleted, Skipped, Warnings ) after performing a query like:

```
dump(DB::connection('mysql')->unprepared(DB::raw($SQLscript)));
```

It seems that I'm getting only true or false if any row is affected.

Comment: Don't get why you're downvoting my question.Laravel DB class documentation doesn't give any hint on how to access low level mysql info after executing statements. Larevel DB class uses PDO, PDO uses mysqli, mysql have a mysql_info() function to retrieve such information. How to bubble up to Larevel DB class that string?

Answer (score -1):

Unprepared returns a boolean value, that's why you're getting a true/false result.

**UPDATE**

Try something like this instead and see what it returns:

```
DB::connection('mysql')->getpdo()->exec(load data infile query...)
```

I don't have an environment to test this, I'm just going on the information you shared and what I know.

Comment: In need to perform a load data infile query. So thats the way i found it working. No chance to get mysql_info?

Comment: Doing  dump(DB::getpdo()->exec(DB::raw($SQLscript))); Gave me back a 0 (zero) instead of false. No additional info.

Comment: Did it upload the data?

Comment: If it doesn't update anything returns false, otherwise true. Anyway this is not the point. The point of the question is how to get mysql information on what's happening.